# export spring to excel

Tags: spring, apache-poi

The problem looks old, the news is that I found working, but only with Firefox. That is the reason I put the question again.
Any answer will be appreciated.
Thanks!

The error message as below:

ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Cannot suppress a null exception.
Self-suppression not permitted
Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/core.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller.

The pom:

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.apache.poi<groupId>    
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml<artifactId>    
   <version>5.1.0<version>
<dependency>
```

//controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/show")
public class ShowCPEController {
CPE cpe;

@Autowired
private CpeService cpeService;

@GetMapping("/export-to-excel")
public void exportIntoExcelFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());

    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = "attachment; filename=CPE, "+mainProiect.getBuilding().getTitular()+ currentDateTime + ".xlsx";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    List <CPE> listOfCpe = cpeService.findAll();

    cpe = cpeService.findByProject(mainProiect.getProjectId());
    mainProiect.setCpe(cpe);
    

    
    CPEtoExcelGenerator generator = new CPEtoExcelGenerator();
    generator.generateExcelFile(response);
}

}
```

// excel class

```
public CPEtoExcelGenerator(){
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
}


public void generateExcelFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    DefineSheet();
    Line1_2();
    Line5();
    Line2127(23, "A", 2, A);
    Line59();
    Line62();
    DrawHomeplate();

    setBorders(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B4:Ap6"), BorderStyle.THIN);
    setBorders(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B8:Ap8"), BorderStyle.THIN);
    setBorders(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:AP61"), BorderStyle.MEDIUM);

    try (ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
      workbook.write(outputStream);
      workbook.close();

  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "excel ouput err: ", e);
  
}
```

}

put already,but posibble not in the correct place:

```
response.getOutputStream().close();
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Wish the app to work in any browser as well as with Firefox

Comment: So which package gives the error? Is it up to date?

Comment: from this command is triggered:    workbook.write(outputStream);

Comment: So, have to stick to simple questions: as it works with Firefox, what does it not work with? Chrome? Safari? Netscape? Mozilla? Explorer?

Comment: Edge, Chrome, Internet Explorer. At the beginning worked fine all, but from a point, I assume as suggested, some updating were coming

Answer (score 0):

I found with very big chance the good answer on below link (search so much also before the answer release).
Tt is because of a stupid comma inside the file name. As removed, everything OK!

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578428/duplicate-headers-received-from-server)