# S3 downloading images with comma in filename results in "net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have stored images that users upload on AWS S3.  When a user views those images in the browser, they have urls that point to my app, where I redirect to a temporary signed url using s3.getSignedUrl.  Everything works great 99% of the time.

The issue is that once in a while a user will upload an image that has a comma in the filename.  When they then try and view that image in Chrome (and only chrome), I get this error

```
net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
```

I figured out that it was the comma since several other people are having a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588818/chrome-pdf-display-duplicate-headers-received-from-the-server) problem which they fixed by setting the content-disposition header.

With s3 and [getSignedUrl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property), this can, I think, be done by setting the ReponseContentDisposition attribute in the params argument.  The specific fix is to either properly quote the filename in the content-disposition or to just set the filename to something else that doesn't contain a comma at all.

That plan, however, isn't working for me.  Anyone have any ideas about the details I might be getting wrong?

My server is Node.js.  Here is the js that is doing the redirect (which like I said normally works great)

```
function tempRedirect(req, res) {
    var filename = req.params[0];
    var params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        ResponseContentDisposition: 'inline; filename=' + filename.replace(/,/, '_'),
        Key: checkTrailingSlash(getFileKeyDir(req)) + filename
    };
    var s3 = new aws.S3(s3Options);
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function(err, url) {
        res.redirect(url);
    });
};
```

Comment: Tried adding `g` flag to `RegExp` `/,/g`?

Comment: Here is the "response-content-disposition" query string parameter from chrome inspector:  response-content-disposition:inline; filename="test,_2.jpg" as an example of one option I tried that didn't work (quoting the filename)

Comment: @guest271314 just tried.  I was pretty sure there was only one comma but good catch still.   Here is the "response-content-disposition" query string when I'm trying to remove the commas:  response-content-disposition:inline; filename=test__2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression in S3.

[AWS Developer Forum - response-content-disposition parameter is not working in S3 GET request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=235006)

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented issue with Google Chrome (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103618).
The issue only occurs when you use a comma in a file name that is uploaded.
To resolve, re-upload the file, but without the comma in the file name.

Please note, this may occur in other browsers as well.